# ViewModel is null when explicitly setting from OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I researched a few questions on SO, but couldn't seem to locate the answer to this.  Who knows, maybe I am breaking best-practice.  After reading an excellent answer on using a layout injector attribute to be able to set the layout by simply specifying an attribute, I figured I could also use this kind of class to attribute controllers which require the user to be authenticated.

So, rather than me having to check authentication everywhere, I wrote the following:

```
    // class AdminAttribute
public class AdminAttribute : LayoutInjectorAttribute
{
    // ctor
    public AdminAttribute()
        : base("_LayoutAdmin")
    {
    }   // eo ctor


    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        WebUser user = WebApplication.CurrentUser;
        if (!user.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() { ViewName = "Unauthorised" };
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = new ViewModel(WebApplication.CurrentUser.Translate("msgunauthorisedtitle"));
            filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext);
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }   // eo OnActionExecuting

}   // eo class AdminAttribute
```

All works, aside from the fact that the model is `null` when processing the view.  Does anyone have an idea why this may be?

The view page (Unauthorised.cshtml)

```
@model Py2.Web.ViewModel
<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
if (!user.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Unauthorised" };
    var model = new ViewModel(
        WebApplication.CurrentUser.Translate("msgunauthorisedtitle")
    );
    result.ViewData.Model = model;
    filterContext.Result = result;
    return;
}
```

Notice that there is no need to call `ExecuteResult` explicitly, that's the job of the ASP.NET MVC frameowrk, simply return the ViewResult by passing it a model (`result.ViewData.Model = model`). Also notice the way this view model is passed to the view result and not to `filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model` as you were doing in your code.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That worked a treat.  What was I doing wrong?  Once again, thank you for your advice.

Comment: @Moo-Juice, you were doing a couple of things wrong as I explained in my answer: 1. you was explicitly calling `filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult`, 2. you was not assigning the view model to the correct object (`filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model`) instead of assigning it to the view result.